# Is there a solution simelar to windows offline folder?

Tags: sync

There are a lot of Sync solutions out there, but they all need a special server.

I only need a 2 way sync tool that sync files with my nas(Synology) when i am at home. even like windows offline files. My nas have ftp, ssh and samba enabled. I dont want to install extra software on my nas!

Do anyone of you know a solution for this problem?

thanks for your help!

Comment: Isn't your NAS simply mounted when you are at home? Being mounted can be simply set as a condition to synchronize. Are you using a (local) sync tool already?

Comment: Im not shure If i understand you. do you mean, i can mont mi Networkdirectory to lacally like /home/nas and sync it with freefilesync? Does the mounted irectory automatically connect to the nas again when i join the network?

Comment: Well, basically yes, you can run a (very lightweight) background script that checks if the NAS is mounted (is it automounted?) and synchronizes it with any software of your choice if it is mounted. I have my NAS (auto) mounted in `/home/jacob/Netwerkmap` and it behaves like a local folder.

Comment: This sounds like a really nice solution. Are you able to send me the script? maybe i can rework it to my needs. this would be really great!! how do you time it with scheduler?